# How to request a URL but not download the response in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

In one of my web applications, customers are allowed to provide URLs that function as a "callback" or notification. (For example, when the `WidgetCreated` event happens, call `http://customerdomain.com/widget.php?widgetid=101`)

All we need to do is make the request; we don't care about the response, for 2 reasons:

- It wastes our bandwidth and performance
- Worst case scenario, an abusive customer sends back a 1GB response to this request

How could I make the request, and download the first, say 1K, and then stop the download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the request with HttpWebRequest and use the GetResponse method.  Instead of reading the response stream, just `return`.

Comment: There is also the ACCEPT_RANGES http header (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) but servers do not have to obey it.

Comment: This seems to work pretty well; the other answers on this question could work too, but this seems to provide greatest compatibility with servers that only support GET.

Answer (score 1):

You could issue a HEAD request.  This only downloads the headers of the page.  So, you're still retrieving content, but you're not pulling the entire page.

The basic gist of it is simply setting the `Method` property to `"HEAD"`.  I leave the rest, including catching exceptions, etc - to you.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: what if the web server allows only GET and POST, which is common?

Comment: @twk: set request.Method = "GET" or "POST". what problem?